# How to set Base URI to Spring WebClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am trying to create a Spring `WebClient` to call REST API. For that, I wrote the following piece of code.

```java
@Bean
public WebClient defaultWebClient() {

    var tcpClient = TcpClient.create()
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 3_000)
            .doOnConnected(connection ->
                    connection.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(3))
                            .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(3)));

    return WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("https://test.com")
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.from(tcpClient)))
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/vnd.api+json")
            .build();
}
```

then the actual URI with the following code.

```java
String user = webClient.get()
                       .uri(URI.create("/api/v1/user/1"))
                       .header("Authorization", TOKEN)
                       .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json")
                       .retrieve()
                       .bodyToMono(String.class)
                       .block();
```

but when the above code executed then it throws the following exception.

```
{"timestamp":"1608209276546","level":"ERROR","thread":"http-nio-8080-exec-1","mdc":{"tenantId":null},"logger":"org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet]","message":"Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:12012; nested exception is io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:12012] with root cause","context":"default","exception":"java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information\r\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)\r\n\tat
```

as raw too:

> {"timestamp":"1608209276546","level":"ERROR","thread":"http-nio-8080-exec-1","mdc":{"tenantId":null},"logger":"org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet]","message":"Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:12012; nested exception is io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:12012] with root cause","context":"default","exception":"java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information\r\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)\r\n\tat

I am not sure where I need to change here so that it starts pointing to base URI instead of localhost (127.0.0.1:12012).
Another thing is if I pass the fully qualified name (https://test.com/api/v1/user/1) on API call then it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

From Javadoc, method [uri(URI uri)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.UriSpec.html#uri-java.util.function.Function-)

> Specify the `URI` using an absolute, fully constructed `URI`

so this version of method does not use base url from configuration.

Instead, you should have specified URI using UriBuilder, which is injected into method [uri(Function<UriBuilder,URI> uriFunction)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.UriSpec.html#uri-java.util.function.Function-).

```
String user = webClient.get()
                       .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/api/v1/user/1").build())
                       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods in `WebClient.UriSpec` that could help.

```
interface UriSpec<S extends RequestHeadersSpec<?>> {

    S uri(String uri, Object... uriVariables);

    S uri(String uri, Map<String, ?> uriVariables);

    ...
}
```

In the simplest case just pass `String` instead of `URI` as the argument.

```
String user = webClient
                .get()
                .uri("/api/v1/user/1")        // <- just String
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using TcpClient, in my version I used HttpClient and had to specify the baseUrl parameter on that as well.
i.e.

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient
                        .create()
                        .baseUrl(getRootUrl())
                        .responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(<timeout in millis>));

return WebClient
                        .builder()
                        .baseUrl(getRootUrl())
                        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                        .defaultHeaders(headers -> {
                            if (!headers.containsKey(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE)) {
                                headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM.toString());
                            }

                            headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessKey);
                        })
                        .build();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is ridiculous. You're setting base URL twice. One of these places is irrelevant. Which one?